# Can we put $\Delta p, \Delta x, \Delta E, \Delta t$ into one big uncertainty equation?

Tags: heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

According to my calculations $x$ * $p$ has unit $[kg m^2/s]$ which is what we would get if we multiply $E$ by $t$

So $$ Et = xp$$

Starting from here, can we some how derive a formula that puts all the big four uncertainties $\Delta p, \Delta x, \Delta E, \Delta t$ together?

Comment: Thy're two well-known pairs, but they're certainly not the only ones. In particular, angular momentum along all three axis forms a triplet (not a pair). Why would your two pairs have physical significance?

Answer (score 2):

No. They are **pairwise** uncerainties.

From the fact that any translation-invariant Hamiltonian fulfills
$$ [H, p] = 0\quad \Rightarrow \quad \Delta E \cdot \Delta p = 0$$
In the meanwhile it is fundamental that
$$ [x, p] = i \hbar \quad \Rightarrow \quad \Delta x \cdot \Delta p \geq \frac{\hbar}{2} $$

**Edit**:

Other questions referred to four-vectors composed of $x^\mu = (ct, \vec x)$ and $p^\nu = (E/c, \vec p)$ where one could write formally
$$ \Delta x^\mu \Delta p^\nu \geq \frac{\hbar}{2} \delta^{\mu \nu}. $$
I personally do not like this approach, since in QFT - the special relativistic version of quantum mechanics - *neither space nor time are operators*. The uncertainty relations are closely linked to the operator algebra, though and this fact gets completely obscured in this four-vector formulation.

Comment: Hi can you please show how you went from the lie bracket to the uncertainty? i can't see how $xp - px = i\hbar$ leads to that. thanks

Comment: the question has $\Delta E \Delta t$. Where is your $\Delta t$?

Comment: @MathNewb: It follows from the Ehrenfest theorem.

Comment: @MathNewb Have a look at the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle#Robertson.E2.80.93Schr.C3.B6dinger_uncertainty_relations)